# How to get the maximum of values of one column assigned to the unique values of another column in dataframe(df) and make a new dataframe

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

My sample dataframe df:

```
 citynames          humidity
0 california           50 
1 malibu               60
2 dc                   18 
3 rossington           25  
4 whetton              26
5 seattle              38            
6 california           47 
7 malibu               65
8 dc                   58
```

How may I achieve this:
newdf

```
citynames     humidity
california     50
malibu         65
.
.
```

Unique citynames and max values of humidity assigned to it

Comment: `df.groupby('citynames')[['humidity']].max()`

Comment: Alternative to groupby `df.sort_values('humidity', ascending=False).drop_duplicates('citynames')`